# DEBUGING Xamarin IOS Extension Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Ios project, and today I added a Shared Extension to allow the user share/upload to our server the files (like text, images, video, .docs, .xlsx, etc). But when I was trying to debug the extesion my Visual Studio ignore the breakpoints. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows pared with my Mac Mini. Does anyone knows how to debug? Or make to save the metadata (like, extension file, name, size of the same)?

Comment: Did you set the extension project as the startup one to enable debugging ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I thought that the start up project had to be the Ios project and all related shared project will automatically stop on breakpoints

Comment: Try to set  extension project as the startup project to see if it solves the problem .